# Return different subset of data when clicking checkbox in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-helper

I am trying to make the simple-todo app as given on Meteor website.

Here's my code or view the complete app on [Meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/6WFWf8zqcymft96PW/simple-todo-app):

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>

      <label class="hide-completed">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{hideCompleted}}" />
        Hide Completed Tasks
      </label>

      <form class="new-task">
        <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
      </form>

    </header>

    <ul>
      {{#each tasks}}
        {{> task}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

```
 Template.body.helpers({
     tasks: function() {
         if (Session.get("hideCompleted")) {
             // If hide completed is checked, filter tasks
             return Tasks.find({
                 checked: {
                     $ne: true
                 }
             }, {
                 sort: {
                     createdAt: -1
                 }
             });
         } else {
             // Otherwise, return all of the tasks
             return Tasks.find({}, {
                 sort: {
                     createdAt: -1
                 }
             });
         }
     },
     hideCompleted: function() {
         return Session.get("hideCompleted");
     }
 });
```

The `hideCompleted` checkbox is not ommiting the checked items from the list and after hours of braking my head over it, I still can't find the bug. Can somebody please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Session.equals(key, value)`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/session_equals) to test if a Session variable is equal to a value.

In your case that would be:

```
 Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
        return Session.equals("hideCompleted", true) ? Tasks.find({checked: {$ne: true}}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}) : Tasks.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
    }
  });
```

Furthermore, you need to register a [click event](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps) to invert the corresponding Session value:

```
 Template.body.events({
    "click #hide-tasks": function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Session.set("hideCompleted", !Session.get("hideCompleted"));
    }
 });
```

---

```
<input id="hide-tasks" type="checkbox" checked="{{hideCompleted}}" />
```

Here's the updated [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/bwmQpDjq9DGY9DkQj/Copy-of-simple-todo-app).